# Access into :namespace option value in custom simple_form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to create new input for simple_form (2.1.0) which is aware of `:namespace` given in `simple_form_for`. Is it possible to get this value inside my class extending `SimpleForm::Inputs::Base`?

Comment: :namespace value is available in: `@builder.options[:namespace]`. After 7h I will be able to close this question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:namespace` value is available in: `@builder.options[:namespace]`.